# Function after async Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

Im new at React, I was trying to make weather website. I want to get the visitor’s IP first, then get the city location, and then get the weather conditions directly through Openweather. Here is my code, I hope someone can help me answer how to complete this website, Thank you

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
require("dotenv").config();

function IpGet() {
  const [ip, setIP] = useState("");
  const [countryName, setcountryName] = useState("");
  const [cityName, setcityName] = useState("");
  const [countryCode, setcountryCode] = useState("");
  const [countryStateName, setcountryStateName] = useState("");

  const WeatherKey = process.env.REACT_APP_WEATHERKEY;

  const getData = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get("https://geolocation-db.com/json/");
    setIP(res.data.IPv4);
    setcountryName(res.data.country_name);
    setcityName(res.data.city);
    setcountryCode(res.data.country_code);
    setcountryStateName(res.data.state);
  };

  // const getWeather = async () => {
  //   const WeatherUrl = await axios.get(
  //     `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityName},${countryStateName}&appid=${WeatherKey}`
  //   );
  // };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="IpGet">
      <h4>{ip}</h4>
      <h4>{countryName}</h4>
      <h4>{countryCode}</h4>
      <h4>{countryStateName}</h4>
      <h4>{cityName}</h4>
    </div>
  );
}

export default IpGet;
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more explicit about what your question is here?

Comment: If you want to fetch data from openweather based on the city, you need to use a second `useEffect` call and `[cityName]` as its dependency array. That way the function inside will run when `cityName` changes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The question is vague but here is a bit of a guess.

A few tips to start with:

- You probably don't need axios for most front-end solutions. It is just an extra dependency. Use the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) instead.
- Keep your variable names consistent - `setCountryName` instead of `setcountryName`.
- The useMemo hook will prevent a function from being created on every render. You can pass the second argument of a dependency array that contains variables. If any of those variables change, `useMemo` will recalculate that function.

Now to the code. You can give `useEffect` the second argument of an array of variables. If any of these variables change, the effect will run the callback function provided as the first arg. `useEffect` will also always run once when the component mounts.

Create a second effect that runs when you get the data needed to make the weather API call.

All things above considered, your code might now look like this (untested):

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
require('dotenv').config();

function IpGet() {
    const [ip, setIP] = useState('');
    const [countryName, setCountryName] = useState('');
    const [cityName, setCityName] = useState('');
    const [countryCode, setCountryCode] = useState('');
    const [countryStateName, setCountryStateName] = useState('');

    const weatherKey = process.env.REACT_APP_WEATHERKEY;

    // useMemo to avoid recreating this function on every render
    const getData = React.useMemo(() => async () => {
        const res = await fetch('https://geolocation-db.com/json/');
        setIP(res.data.IPv4);
        setCountryName(res.data.country_name);
        setCityName(res.data.city);
        setCountryCode(res.data.country_code);
        setCountryStateName(res.data.state);
    });

    const getWeather = React.useMemo(() => async () => {
        if (!cityName || !countryStateName || !weatherKey) return;

        const weatherUrl = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityName},${countryStateName}&appid=${weatherKey}`;
        const weatherData = await fetch(weatherUrl);

        // Do something with weatherData here... set to some state or something.
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        getData();
    }); // No dependency array, so this will only run once when the component mounts

    useEffect(() => {
        getWeather();
    }, [cityName, countryStateName]); // This will trigger the callback when any of these variables change.

    return (
        <div className='IpGet'>
            <h4>{ip}</h4>
            <h4>{countryName}</h4>
            <h4>{countryCode}</h4>
            <h4>{countryStateName}</h4>
            <h4>{cityName}</h4>
        </div>
    );
}

export default IpGet;
```